# SELECT Hüsby returns the 'wrong' output Husby

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

In the same database, I run the query and get one correct and one incorrect result.

**correct**

```
SELECT Ort FROM `stammdaten` WHERE `Ort` = 'Husby';
    
Ort 
Husby   
Husby
```

**wrong**

```
SELECT Ort FROM stammdaten WHERE Ort = 'Hüsby';

Ort
Husby
Husby
```

database : utf8mb4_unicode_ci

table    : utf8mb4_unicode_ci

field    : utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Does anyone have any ideas what else I can change or check?

Comment: What is the difference between `correct` and `wrong` (the results seem to be the same)? What is expected?

Comment: @Luuk The second query has diaresis over the `u`, but it's returning values that don't have that.

Comment: Yes, but that is because of the `_ci` in the collating sequence .

Comment: The `%unicode%` collations are a decade old; I recommend moving away from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the documentation, because everything works as expected:

- [10.3.1 Collation Naming Conventions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-collation-names.html): "*Collation suffixes indicate whether a collation is case-sensitive, accent-sensitive, or kana-sensitive (or some combination thereof), or binary.*" The table shows that the suffix `_ci` at least stands for "**c**ase **i**nsensitivity".
- "*For nonbinary collation names that do not specify accent sensitivity, it is determined by case sensitivity. If a collation name does not contain `_ai` or `_as`, `_ci` in the name implies `_ai` and `_cs` in the name implies `_as`.*" So the collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is **also accent insensitive**.
- If you want accent **sensitivity** but at the same time case **insensitivity** then choose `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci` as per [10.2 Character Sets and Collations in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html).
- Blindly casting columns and/or literals as a `BINARY` type is not the same as applying the `utf8mb4_bin` collation, as it in general comes with more restrictions. See [10.8.5 The binary Collation Compared to _bin Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html).

Unicode needs to be understood (`ü` versus `u¨`), case insensitivity rules need to be understood (`ß` versus `SS`), and accent insensitivity need to be understood ([`Café`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Caf%C3%A9) versus [`cafè`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/caf%C3%A8)). Otherwise you end up having data stored which you are unable to properly find or filter by because you chose the wrong collation. Understanding the sorting is also an aspect (does `ü` sort after `u` or after `ö`?), although rarily of interest.

Comment: The latest MySQL 8.0 has `utf8mb4_0900_as_ci` and 32 `utf8mb4_%_0900_as_cs` collations.  See `SHOW COLLATION LIKE '%as%';`.   `utf8mb4_ja_0900_as_cs_ks` is the one available kana-sensitive collation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BINARY to compare

> ```
> CREATE TABLE stammdaten (Ort varchar(10)) CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4 COLLATE Utf8mb4_unicode_ci
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO stammdaten VALUES('Husby')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT Ort FROM stammdaten WHERE BINARY Ort = BINARY 'Hüsby';
> ```
>
> ```
> | Ort |
> | :-- |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0d9d339b5a924aece35df0a260cf55e9)*

Comment: Why forcing an entirely different data type instead of setting a different collation to the query?

Comment: Converting to binary y ist the standard procedure in these cases. Changing the collation can lead the lots of trouble also I doubt that it will slow down the queries

Answer (score 0):

[I listed all collations to see](https://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8mb4_collations.html) that Hungarian and Turkish treat `ü` as a separate letter between `u` and `v`. If that is what you need, switch to `utf8mb4_hu_0900_ai_ci` or `utf8mb4_tr_0900_ai_ci`.

Probably `ALTER TABLE ... CONVERT TO COLLATION utf8mb4_hu_0900_ai_ci;` would suffice. Caution: It needs to be done for all tables that will be `JOIN`ed on such strings, and it will convert all non-UTF-8 columns, too.  So, test in a separate environment.

If `CONVERT TO` is too much of a sledge hammer, then consider `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY col ...`, but be sure to include other attributes of the column.

`utf8mb4_polish_ci` and the generic `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` treat `u`=`ü`.  On the other hand, any `utf8mb4%as%` collation will treat *all* accents as different.

The German collations treated umlaut-u as equal to `ue`:

```
mysql> select 'ue'='ü', 'u' = 'ü';
+-----------+------------+
| 'ue'='ü'  | 'u' = 'ü'  |
+-----------+------------+
|         0 |          1 |
+-----------+------------+

mysql> select 'ue'='ü' COLLATE utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_ai_ci, 'u' = 'ü' COLLATE utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_ai_ci;
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| 'ue'='ü' COLLATE utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_ai_ci  | 'u' = 'ü' COLLATE utf8mb4_de_pb_0900_ai_ci  |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|                                          1 |                                           0 |
+--------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+

mysql> select 'ue'='ü' COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci, 'u' = 'ü' COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci;
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| 'ue'='ü' COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci  | 'u' = 'ü' COLLATE utf8mb4_turkish_ci  |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
|                                    0 |                                     0 |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: "_stammdaten_" implies German; both [Husby](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Husby) and [Hüsby](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hüsby) are German, too. I sense neither Turkish nor Hungarian are of interest. In the [German alphabet](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_Alphabet) umlauts are different letters, not accent versions of vowels: [schon](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schon) and [schön](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schön) are completely different words. DBMSes by default want to be `ai` since most foreigners opt to write at least non-umlauts, hence wanting to find both. OP did not.

Comment: @AmigoJack - "Different letter" -- as in equivalent to "ue".  I added queries to demonstrate some comparisons.  (I picked Polish because of the OP's last name.)